# css conditional statements: include stylesheet for IE8+ and rest

Tags: css

I have this stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
```

And I want to include it for IE8+ and any other browser but **not** to include for IE7-. Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
I have tried:

```
<!--[if (gte IE 8)|(!IE)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But that does not include the file under Firefox or Chrome (or any other browser than IE8+ I suppose)

**EDIT2:**
In fact, I should include the file for IE9+ (not IE8+) because I have just found out not even IE8 supports media queries. Anyway this does not matter in terms of "how to do this stuff".

Comment: Do a search for "IE conditional" and you should find it. The technique uses HTML comments.

Comment: +1. This is more tricking than what it seems

Comment: The techniques are out there. I would include the responsive stylesheet for all browsers, then use the conditional to "negate" any responsive rules that mess with IE7 and below. Or, if your site is already JavaScript-driven, there's no need to be one of those stoic purists out there... just use JavaScript for the condition and load the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

There are some special syntax in [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

```
gt: greater than
lte: less than or equal to
```

So you can use them to filter.

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Conditional Comments also supports [multiple condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using `AND(&)` or `OR(|)` operator

```
<!--[if (gt IE 7)|(!IE)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: With this, the file is not included in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: for that you can use or condition and try this statement `<!--[if gt IE 7 |(!IE)]>`

Comment: even `<!--[if gt IE 7 |(!IE)]>` does not do the thing under Firefox/Chrome

Comment: Exactly, because the (!IE) part is read only by IE, not by other browsers :/

Answer (score 0):

Include your Old IE CSS file in a conditional statement, then include your normal CSS file

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/bootstrap/css/OLD-IE.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
```